# Display Popup once when Site is loaded

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I want a `pop up` to be opened first whenever the site is opened for the first time. Please suggest me what will be the easiest way of doing this.

In `codebehind`, `jquery`, or `javascript`

Comment: Popup or a modal window?

Comment: Opened for the first time, as in "see the popup once per day"?, "once when the site is opened and never again?", etc. Either way, I'm thinking use a cookie and check it on page load.

Comment: @Zentaurus : i want modal window

Comment: Try something. Try bootstrap modal. If you're stuck, ask for help ang give us your code, but try something first

Comment: @mrunion : i want second one.

Comment: Use a cookie, check it when the page loads from JavaScript, and either show the modal or not based on the date you would write in the cookie. As for the code to do all that, take a crack at it and post back here if you are stuck on specifics.

Answer (score 1):

This would do that if you are OK with this working per-browser, and also it would not work for older browsers http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage.

```
if(!localStorage.siteLoaded){
    alert('Welcome!'); //Or any other pop up method...
    localStorage.siteLoaded = true;
}
```